# Determine the sequence of coefficients $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N_0}}$ so that: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n = \frac{e^x}{1-x} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Assignment: Determine the sequence of coefficients $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N_0}}$ so that

> $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n = \frac{e^x}{1-x}\ , \forall x\in\mathbb{R}: |x|  < 1. $$

What I've got so far is this:  $\frac{e^x}{1-x}\ = e^x \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!} \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^k $ But how do I continue from here, do i have to calculate the Cauchy Product of the two sequences?

If I define  $b_n:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!} $ and $ c_n:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^k $.

Generally the Cauchy Product is: $d_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n b_kc_{n-k} = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}x^{n-k} = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^n}{k!}$

Does this help me in any way? And how do I embed my result so I get the  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ - form back?

Hints are just appreciated as solutions.

Comment: It might be easier to multiply both sides by $1-x$ and then see this gives you a recursive equation for the $a_i$.

Comment: You have it pretty much written down. $$a_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}.$$

Comment: So: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!})x^n = \frac{e^x}{1-x}$ ?

Comment: Right. All you had to do was extracting the common factor $x^n$ from your formula for $d_n$ to get a power series.

Comment: I was not quite sure if I could just take the $x^n$ from the inner sum and put into the outer sum without changing its value, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $$e^x = (1-x)\sum_n a_n x^n = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n-a_{n-1})x^n$$

So $a_0=1$ and $a_n-a_{n-1} = \frac{1}{n!}$.